# Where is NoScript in Tor Browser for Android?

Tags: android

Recently switched from Orfox to Tor Browser for Android (Alpha).  The NoScript settings seem to be gone from the main menu.  How can I selectively enable javascript for only the domains I trust?

Please note that this question is specifically about Tor Browser for Android (Alpha), not desktop TorBrowser or the Orfox Android app.

I am aware that Mozilla's recent armagadd-on issue disabled add-ons for a little while, however at this time, Mozilla has fixed that issue and noscript is working again in desktop TorBrowser, and in Orfox.  However, even after turning xpinstall.signatures.required off in about:config, no addons are present in Tor Browser for Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is described in TOR blog, noscript is temporary disabled.

https://blog.torproject.org/noscript-temporarily-disabled-tor-browser

Comment: Mozilla has already fixed the certificate issue, and addons work fine in desktop torbrowser and in orfox.  
see: https://blog.torproject.org/new-release-tor-browser-809

Comment: Today, I've update my TOR browser and all the problems have been solved.

Comment: Updating did not fix it for me, but after completely uninstalling and reinstalling a couple times, I do finally have add-ons.